# Pass in subvector of vector into a function

Tags: c++, vector, parameters, std

So let's say I have an

```
std::vector<int> myVector;
```

and a function

```
myFunction(std::vector<int> parameter);
```

I want to be able to pass a subvector of myVector to myFunction without having to copy the elements over into a new vector first. Can this be done?

Comment: See the duplicate from earlier today. I think it covers your use case.

Comment: My eyes are bad ... where is the link to the duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Make your function take iterator range instead, for example:

```
template< class Iterator, class T >
void myFunction( Iterator first, Iterator last, const T& value );
```

Comment: Why is the third argument used? Wouldn't the 2 iterators be enough?